# Why is it "Exception as e" not "Error as e"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it just an idiosyncrasy of the language - I get that in the hierarchy they might've wanted the "Warning" as well, but wouldn't it massively help clarity if parent was Error, rather than Exception?

https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/exception-handling-python

What else am I missing?

Comment: Trivia: Warnings *are* Exceptions. `issubclass(UserWarning, Exception) is True`.

Comment: Are you asking why the `Exception` class in Python is named `Exception` and not `Error`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant to ask **why the `Exception` class is not called `Error`**:

What you're missing is that **every exception is not at error**.

Therefore, deriving errors from an exception makes more sense because it will always be possible to do so. If exceptions were to be derived from errors, it would imply that every exception is an error, which is clearly not the case.

You can find a good explanation here:

[Why are Python exceptions named "Error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903827/why-are-python-exceptions-named-error)

[Why are errors named as exception but not as error in programming languages?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161488/why-are-errors-named-as-exception-but-not-as-error-in-programming-languages)